# New shower not heating up

Tags: bathroom, water, shower

I recently had a big bathroom remodel done. We installed a new shower head and valve as well as a new universal multi choice cable body. Anyway, the shower used to heat up quickly and be able to get very hot and last a long time. But now, the water gets warm and dies out after maybe 10 minutes. The shower has been used for a week now.

Comment: What model is all this kit?

Comment: What is the source of your hot water? What's the flow rate of your new head compared with the old one?